# WhiteboxGAT Map Gully Depth Parametrization

Tags: whitebox-gat

I'm trying to extract the ditch network from a DEM with the map gully depth tool in Whiteboxgat. Does anyone know about parameterization methodologies or where can I find them?
I found only two cases of application of this tool: Mahor et al. (2016) and Gustavsson and Selberg (2018)